# Client-side object model - How same piece of code can load every SP object based on URL?

Tags: csom

I need to retrieve some data from SharePoint objects file, folder, list, web, attachment  - all possible objects (hope that i didn't miss any). 
Since i need to retrieve the data i need only based on URL of the SP object i have a trouble distinguishing between the different object, and that creates a problem with loading the objects correctly.
Meaning the following code:

```
ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url);
ctx.Load(folder);
try
{
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a folder url  {0}, the following exception was trown {1}\n", url, ex.Message);
}
```

Will work for folder relative URL, such as : "/shared%20documents/f1/f2".
But won't work for file relative URL, such as : "/shared%20documents/f1/file.txt".
But i have noticed that the code for List:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = ctx.Web.GetList(url);
ctx.Load(list);
try
{
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Not a List url  {0}, the following exception was trown {1}\n", url, ex.Message);
}
```

**Works not just for list but also for folders, it returns

 */shared%20documents*

for */shared%20documents/f1/f2* relative URL !**
**That brings the following questions:**
Do all SP objects can be divided to List and List items (regular folder,file,attachment,list item = list item)?
If yes what about the web object?
How many actors SP online has?
Is it possible to distinguish between the actors types based on their URL?
It it possible to create a  peace of code can that would be able to  load every SP object based on URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know the type of the object based only on it URL.
To determine the object type the object can be loaded As File or folder, then in case of failure load as list item, then in case of failure as attachment , then in case of failure as List and in case of failure with some checks on the url determine if it is a site/web url.